# No subject alternative DNS name matching proxy Name found using Mule ESB

Tags: java, mule

I am using Mule 3.7. I have one web service consumer connector. It is trying to access external web service but getting below exception. I am able to access service through SOAPUI with same proxy.

===============
Root Exception stack trace: 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching proxyName found. 
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:191) 
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93) 
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347) 
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:255)

============ Code ============================

```
<data-mapper:config name="Home_Loan_Mapper" transformationGraphPath="home_loan_mapper.grf" doc:name="Home_Loan_Mapper"/>
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="crmod/Contact.wsdl" service="Contact" port="Contact" serviceAddress="serviceURL" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Configuration">
<ws:security>
<ws:wss-username-token username="userID" password="password" passwordType="TEXT" addCreated="true" addNonce="true"/>
<ws:wss-timestamp expires="30000" />
</ws:security>
</ws:consumer-config>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="0.0.0.0" port="8083">
<tls:context>
<tls:trust-store path="C:\Dev\certificates\greenmail-truststore" password="password"/>
<tls:key-store path="clientKeystore" keyPassword="mulepassword" password="mulepassword"/>
</tls:context>
<http:proxy host="proxyName" port="89" username="userID" password="password"/>
</http:request-config>
<flow name="Home_Loan">
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.emailBody]" doc:name="Home Loan"/>
<data-mapper:transform config-ref="Home_Loan_Mapper" doc:name="Home Loan Mapper"/>
<set-variable variableName="homeLoanEnquiry" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set home loan Variable"/>
<choice doc:name="Choice">
<when expression="#[payload.existingcustomer == 'Yes']">
<custom-transformer
class="ContactServiceTransformer"
doc:name="Create Contact Query Page Request" mimeType="text/xml" />
<set-payload value="#[homeLoanEnquiry.contactQueryPageRequest]"
doc:name="Set Contact Request in payload" />
<ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" doc:name="Contact Consumer"
operation="ContactQueryPage" />
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.homeLoanEnquiry]" doc:name="Set Home Loan bean in payload" />
</when>
<otherwise>
<logger message="No customer account" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</otherwise>
</choice>
<custom-transformer class="HoamLoanTransformer" doc:name="Hoam Loan Validation & SOAP Request Gerneration"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've encounter a [bug](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8779). This was fixed in 3.7.1. Replacing the async-http-client jar for version [1.9.27](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ning/async-http-client/1.9.27) should work if you can't update. HTH.